# opengl, convert spherical coordicate from cartesian coordicate

Tags: opengl

I try to find the angles theta and phi in Spherical coordinate from a point in Cartesian coordinate system.

The answer I found, It's not correct. But I can't figure out what's going on.
Please help me.

Here's my code:

```
Vector4 g_eye(8.0f, 8.0f, 8.0f);

Vector4 g_lookat(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

Vector4 g_up(0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f);

struct spherical_sys
{

    spherical_sys(Vector4& p)
    {
        _dirty = 1;
       _pos = p;
       _pos.w = 0.0f;
       get_spherical(_pos, _theta, _phi, _r);
    }

    float getTheta()
    {
       return _theta;
    }

    float getPhi()
    {
       return _phi;
    }

    void setTheta(float t)
    {
       _theta = t;
       _dirty = 1;
    }

    void setPhi(float t)
    {
       _phi = t;
       _dirty = 1;
    }

    Vector4 get_pos()
    {
       if (_dirty)
       {
           float sin_phi, cos_phi;
           float sin_theta, cos_theta;
           FastMath::SinCos(_phi, sin_phi, cos_phi);
           FastMath::SinCos(_theta, sin_theta, cos_theta);

           _pos.w = 0.0f;
           _pos[0] = _r* cos_phi * cos_theta;
           _pos[1] = _r* sin_phi;
           _pos[2] = _r* cos_phi * sin_theta;
           _dirty = 0;
       }
       return _pos;
   }
private:
   void get_spherical(Vector4& dir, float& theta, float& phi, float& r)
   {
       r = dir.Length();
       dir.Normalize();
       phi = FastMath::ACos(Vector3Dotf(dir, Vector4(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f)));
       Vector4 v = Vector3CrossProduct(Vector4(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f), dir);
       if (v.x < 0.0f)
       {
           phi *= -1;
           phi = phi + MATH_PI * 0.5f;
       }
       else
       {
           phi = phi - MATH_PI * 0.5f;
       }
        theta = FastMath::ACos(Vector3Dotf(dir, Vector4(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f)));
        v = Vector3CrossProduct(Vector4(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f), dir);
       if (v.y < 0.0f)
       {
           theta *= -1;
       }
    }
    float _phi;
    float _theta;
    float _r;
    Vector4 _pos;
    int _dirty;
};
spherical_sys _teye(g_eye);
spherical_sys _tup(g_up);
```

The answer of _teye.get_pos().x, _teye.get_pos().y, _teye.get_pos().z was 6.531521, -7.998896, -9.238880.

Obviously, something is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a couple problems.  I won't comment on your code structure, just the conversions....

For reference, here are the equations for [Cartesian-Spherical conversions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system#Cartesian_coordinates).

Your conversions to Cartesian from Spherical are incorrect.  It looks both backwards and ... wrong. Here are the correct equations (see notes below about swapping y/z)

```
       _pos[0] = _r* sin_theta * cos_phi;
       _pos[1] = _r* sin_theta * sin_phi;
       _pos[2] = _r* cos_theta;
```

The Dot product in your equation is useless, the result is just the `y` component of the vector:

```
phi = FastMath::ACos(dir.y);
```

Another issue is that you seem to have swapped the Y and Z axes. This is fine as long as you stay consistent.  Even with this swap, your conversions from spherical to Cartesian are still incorrect.  Let's stay with classical.

```
phi = FastMath::ACos(dir.z);
```

Next, you're using the cross product to help fix the range of the `acos` function.  This is a 'clever' trick, until you [compute the product by hand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product#Matrix_notation) and see that you are literally only checking the Z coordinate.

```
cross( (0,1,0), (x,y,z) ) => (z,0,-x)
```

Next, we'll examine the theta computation:

```
theta = FastMath::ACos(Vector3Dotf(dir, Vector4(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f)));
```

Again, the Dot prodcut is useless, you are just grabbing the `x`

```
theta = FastMath::ACos(dir.x);
```

Simplified, you can see that you are missing components and are using the wrong trig function.  Use ArcTan and *not* ArcCos.

```
theta = ATan2(dir.y, dir.x);
```

Again, looks like you're using the cross product to fix the range.  However computing the product by hand:

```
cross ( (1,0,0) , (x,y,z) ) => (0,-z,y)
```

So you are again simply checking the sign of the `dir.z` component, no need for extra computations.

---

My advice is to use classical equations to convert back and forth at first.  Don't worry about fixing the ranges, you can do that later when you have your code working.

Once that is working, fix the ranges.  After the ranges are correct, then worry about swapping the Z and Y axis (or don't).

If you are unsure of what the Dot product or Cross product is doing, work it out by hand.  Ignoring the geometric significance of these functions, you'll see that they are wasting calculations and generally complicating your code.

Good luck!

Comment: It looks like the dir vector is normalized, which means that the divide by `r` in the `phi` and `theta` calculations are incorrect, I'll fix that now...

Comment: In my original thought, acos( dot(dir, unit_z) ) can find the phi, and same as theta acos( dot(dir, unit_x) ) can find the angle between two directions. But maybe something wrong.

Comment: `phi` is different from `theta`.  It has a different range `[-pi,pi]`.  It's the angle between vector and X,Y plane.  `Theta` is a full circle direction in the X,Y plane, [0,2pi].   Cheers!

Comment: I got the point. It should be using proj(dir) to find the theta. Thanks James.